# Using onWrite Trigger for Realtime database in Firebase function

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, google-cloud-functions

I designed a flutter application using dart and firebase backend. I want to get triggered when a user **creates, delete,** or **updates** anything in the database. I understood **onCreate,onRemoved,** and **onUpdate** methods.
I wrote a javascript code in the firebase cloud function. I need to send a notification when a trigger happens. I don't want to use 3 different triggers. I want to use onWrite trigger only.

This is my database.

[image]

There are four departments called **comp, civil, elect,** and **mech**. I want to get triggered when database changes happen in a single onWrite trigger!

My First question is, I want to **differentiate** whether it is **created or delete or update** from **onWrite** trigger. I know it will trigger for all 3 events. But how can I differentiate it?

This is my code for onCreate...

```
exports.noticeAddedComp = functions.database.ref('main/notices/comp/{id}').onCreate( async evt =>  {

var token = ['dxnfr3dq6_Y:APA91bHavtoP62l296qzVoBhzQJbMFA']
const payload = {
    notification:{
        title : 'Message from Cloud',
        body : 'This is your body',
        sound : 'default'
    },
    data:{
    message : 'Thi is new Push',
    click_action : 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
    }
};
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token,payload);
```

});

Above code is working. But it is for onCreate.

My second question is, Do I need to write four onWrite trigger codes for four departments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `change.before` and `change.after` properties to determine whether the node was created, deleted, or updated in a `onWrite` handler:

```
exports.noticeAddedComp = functions.database.ref('main/notices/comp/{id}')
.onWrite( async (change, context) =>  {
  if (!change.before.exists()) console.log("New node: "+change.after.key);
  if (!change.after.exists()) console.log("Deleted node: "+change.before.key);
  if (change.before.exists() && change.after.exists()) console.log("Updated node: "+change.after.key)
  ...
});
```

---

You can attach a Cloud Function to all departments at once, by including another parameter into its path:

```
exports.noticeAddedComp = functions.database.ref('main/notices/{dept}/{id}')
.onWrite( async (change, context) =>  {
  console.log("Triggered for department: "+context.params.dept);
  ...
})
```

Comment: This answer is cool and helpful. But you said something about *include another parameter into it's path* . But I don't understand it. What will be the return for context.params.dept?

Comment: That's the value from the database path that triggered the function here `functions.database.ref('main/notices/{dept}/{id}')`.

Comment: Sorry. I tried above method. But I'm always getting true for change.after and change.before ? Do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if 
`evt.after.data().property;` 
is either null or doesn't exist, meaning it is deleted.

EDIT:

Scenario when you create something (document or field) :

Creation of the field would mean that the field in "before" doesn't exist at all, and in "after" it exists, but can be null.

Scenario when you update something

Field in the "before" is not the same as the one in "after".

Comment: Can you please write an example? How to identify create and update?